# How to transfer all postfix incoming mail to php script

Tags: postfix-mta

I am using postfix and devecot to receive incoming mails.

I want to transfer particular user with subdomain to a php script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just tell your script to POP or IMAP emails from this inbox ?